# How to find..lead ids

Tags: leads, web2lead

I have a one question.in lead object we have captured lead from web to lead and another one is manually.how to find out these leads which one is web to lead and manually entered lead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no automated feature to identify how a Lead is created. However, there's a way to show that a Lead has been created using Web-To-Lead.

Please go through the below link,
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000220909&language=en_US

That is by:
- Adding the "Lead Source" field when creating the Web-to-lead code
- With the assistance of the Web master/Web Developer, auto-populate the field with the value of the Lead Source by modifying the generated HTML code and set the field to hidden

You could update the Lead Source field with multiple values (e.g. the Web page names) depending on the page that the Web-to-Lead code will be embedded into; that way if you have multiple Web-To-Lead pages created then it could identify which Website it is coming from.

Here is a Sample of how the code could look:

Note: Salesforce provides just the standard Web-to-Lead form but we don't support any particular modification to the form and changes are to be decided by the Org's Administrator or the webmaster deploying the code to the website. If you're facing an issue with records not being created we encourage you to review the default web-to-lead code and see if it works as expected, if so, you'd need to review what modifications have been introduced to the code we provide

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Please provide the appropriate content from the link into your answer (with references).  Links are prone to break in future.